# facebook integration with android app

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I want to integrate facebook login and comment feature into my app. I want to know if a user is logged in into my app using facebook credentials then they comment on some page of my app, will these comments be stored on facebook's servers or I will have to save it on my servers. It would be also great if some tutorial on how to add these features could be shared.

Comment: check out this : https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook

Comment: check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android there's all you need

Comment: Haresh this seems to be great link . But i want to know do you know any app which uses this api or have to personally used it , in any of your apps.